# removal of subfloor for exterior wall

Tags: subfloor

This wall is an exterior wall and has 2 layers of flooring, with the wall sitting on top of the floor. I want to remove the flooring and install advantack t&G.I would like to leave the bottom layer an inch or so off the wall, but would like to remove the top layer along the edge of the wall 2x4. Any thoughts on the idea, or tool to use?

Answer (score 1):

In order to cut a layer of the floor out flush with the bottom plate of the wall, one good tool for the job would be a [Rockwell Sonicrafter](http://www.rockwelltools.com/en-US/SC-Hyperlock-RK5140K.aspx?gclid=CJbbzM6Bpr0CFQ2hOgodoiwAJw)

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mike, I still haven't figured out how to condense those links.

Comment: The [markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#basic-links) should help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a "[toe kick saw](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005SSNMCC)".

[image]

It's a tiny circular saw that's made for what you're doing.  The oscillating saw, like shirlock recommends would be nice to have for any corners or spaces where you can't fit the toe kick saw.